# How can I make a table with random numbers?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that creates a 10x10 table.

I'm using `rand` to generate random numbers on the table.

My problem is that `rand` function generates me a table with the same number in all places.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void Table()
{
    using namespace std;

    srand(time(0));

    int Nums = rand() % 10;
    int Table_size = 10;

    cout << "\n Please wait while we creating your table..."; Sleep(4000);

    for (int i = 0; i < Table_size; i++)  {
        cout << "\n" << Nums;
        for (int i = 0; i < Table_size; i++){
            cout << Nums;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Table();
    return 0;
}
```

**My Current Output:**

I use 7 as example of my table

```
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
7777777777
```

**Excepted Output:**

For Example:

```
2492573583
2321414123
2166234242
6234234266
9234823482
4923942424
1321319311
4682324923
2692392623
1142936077
```

Comment: Why are you generating the random number only once, before the loop, then?

Comment: `int Nums = rand() % 10;` generates 1 random number total. No matter how many times you look at the `Nums` variable. c++ executes this once. It's not a mathematical relationship that is recalculated every time you look at a variable.

Comment: You have a few issues. First, you need a different variable than `i` for your inner loop (like `j` or `k`). Second, you need to generate the random number for each column of each row. The `int Nums = rand() % 10;` needs to go before `cout << Nums;` in the inner loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generate a random number with

```
int Nums = rand() % 10;
```

This generates a single random number **one time**. Then you reuse that value every time you do

```
cout << Nums;
```

If you want a new number each time the loop iterates, you need to generate the random number inside your for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Table_size; i++)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < Table_size; i++){
            int Nums = rand() % 10;
            cout << Nums;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```